# UIScrollView is automatically scrolling a random amount in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uikit

I have an iPhone app that starts out in portrait mode. When the app is rotated to landscape a new view is pushed on using:

```
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

This landscape view contains a UIScrollView that scrolls vertically in the landscape position. The scroll view frame height is equal to the landscape height (320 points) and the content size height of the scroll view is 3 times the landscape height (so 960 points). I have vertical paging enabled, so there are 3 pages.

When the view appears, the scroll view is scrolled to the top as I expect. But in iOS 5, the scroll view then randomly jumps to some position where it is scrolled up. I've commented out my viewDidAppear method and it still does this. In iOS 6 it works fine and this doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Hi. Difficult to say without the whole code. I don't see any particular reason and never had this problem before. If you want to make sure the scrollView is at the top, add something like setContentOffset:CGPointZero in the "viewWillAppear". But you shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: The problem is that the offset show up until after the view has already appeared. I can put a break point in viewDidAppear and when the code breaks, there is no offset and the view is fully presented. But when I continue execution the offset appears. There is no code in my view controller that executes after viewDidAppear, so I'm really at a loss as to what is happening.

Comment: Maybe it's because the view is created in portrait and the offset is done in the "orientation" process, but I'm no sure. Try to add some logs in the "rotate methods". But again, without the whole code, it's hard to help you debugging :/

Comment: Actually I tried your suggestion in the viewDidLoad and it solved the problem! Something must be happening behind the scenes in the UIScrollView class. Can you add your suggestion as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: done ;-) thanks. Not the best way to deal with your problem, but should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So add a [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero] in the viewWillAppear (or somewhere else).

Could help, but not the best way to deal with it ;-)